# Removing Code From MainActivity

Tags: android

I am still new to Android development, and I still don't know a decent way to write code. Currently I throw everything into my `MainActivity`. But I don't think that is a good way to write it. I have been searching Google, but I don't really know what to search for. Does anyone have any tips?

I was going to try and take some code that I have and throw it into a view, but when I do I get errors.

For example when I place this in a view, I get `cannot find symbol LOCATION_SERVICE`

```
public class MainView extends View{
    public double[] getLoc(){
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

That is basically a snippet from a function that gets a users latitude and longitude. It doesn't work in a view I assume. The code does work in my MainActivity though.

Comment: you want to get the current latitude and longitude?

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how Java or any OOP language works for that matter. Android development is still Java. By the way, `LOCATION_SERVICE` is a field in the `Context` class.

Comment: As A--C suggested, you need to learn Java if you don't already know it and go through the Android docs to get you started then ask a more specific question since it sounds like this is just an example of a problem you are having. Answers to fix the location example aren't going to fix the original question of "a decent way to write code". Where to put the code depends on what you are doing with it. Is it `UI` code, belongs in a `static class`, or somewhere entirely different. This is why you need to know OOP and read the Android Docs

Comment: I do know OOP, I am still learning the Java and Android API's though. Okay, so then When should I use an Activity and when should I use a View?

Comment: @RyanNaddy : if you are using this code inside MainView class then need to use as `GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment)context.getFragmentManager(). findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` where `context` is your Fragment or Activity context

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I deleted it beacuse I got it, but it is actually this: `MapFragment mf = MapFragment.newInstance(); map = ((MapFragment)mf.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: @RyanNaddy : both is same way but point is you will need a context instance for accessing getFragmentManager method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
LocationManager locationManager =
                     (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

instead of

```
LocationManager locationManager = 
                     (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

for accessing `LOCATION_SERVICE`

and you also need to use current context for calling getSystemService method to get Service as :

```
public class MainView extends View{
Context context;

public MainView(Context context){
this.context=context;
}

   public double[] getLoc(){
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = 
           (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanNaddy : if you are using this code inside MainView class then need to use  as `GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment)context.getFragmentManager(). findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` where context is your Fragment or Activity context

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in Context to your other classes and View classes to do what you did in Main Actvitity. Like this:

```
public void doStuff(Context context){
    LocationManager locationManager =(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
```

In your Activity you can:

```
doStuff(getBaseContext());
```

to use this method